# Is there an easier way to get the number of variables in an SPSS file than OMS or Python scripting?

Tags: performance, variables, spss

I have been trying my brain and googling all of the place to figure out if there is an easy way to get the number of variables in a datafile purely using syntax. The reason for this is that I work with a lot of small files to which I need to merge new data. However, if you do this programatically, there is a chance due to wrongly types variable names, a new variable will be added to the dataset if it does not already exist.

Hence I want to know the number of variables before a merge and after a merge. For this I have tried to write a macro, but SPSS macro's are really terrible at arimetric and you cannot seem to feed these macro's with the keyword "ALL" (IE: all variables).

Additionally I have looked for syntax which exports info about the dataset to the output where the number of variables will be directly shown. As far as I could find, this did not exist.

So I have in fact managed to make it work via OMS (output management system), but the way is super convoluted and is a lot of lines of text per datafile. See below:

```
* Create datafile to check if merge went okay.
DATA LIST LIST /FileName(A50) N_PRE(F8) N_POST(F8).
DATASET NAME CheckList.

* Open basefile.
GET FILE='DATAFILE_BASE.sav'.
DATASET NAME Data WINDOW=FRONT.

* Set settings to show variable names instead of variable labels in output.
SET Small=0.0001 THREADS=AUTO TVars=Names OVars=Labels TNumbers=Labels ONumbers=Labels DIGITGROUPING=No LEADZERO=No ODISPLAY=tables.

* Use OMS to determine number of variables.
DATASET DECLARE COUNT.
OMS
  /SELECT TABLES
  /IF COMMANDS=['Frequencies'] SUBTYPES=['Frequencies']
  /DESTINATION FORMAT=SAV NUMBERED=TableNumber_
   OUTFILE='COUNT' VIEWER=YES
  /TAG='Frequencies'.
FREQUENCIES ALL.
OMSEND TAG = ['Frequencies'].

* Retain only variable names and remove duplicates.
DATASET ACTIVATE COUNT.
ADD FILES FILE *
    /KEEP Label_,.
EXECUTE.
SORT CASES BY Label_(A).
MATCH FILES
  /FILE=*
  /BY Label_
  /FIRST=PrimaryFirst
  /LAST=PrimaryLast.
DO IF (PrimaryFirst).
COMPUTE  MatchSequence=1-PrimaryLast.
ELSE.
COMPUTE  MatchSequence=MatchSequence+1.
END IF.
LEAVE  MatchSequence.
FORMATS  MatchSequence (f7).
COMPUTE  InDupGrp=MatchSequence>0.
SORT CASES InDupGrp(D).
MATCH FILES
  /FILE=*
  /DROP=PrimaryFirst InDupGrp MatchSequence.
SELECT IF (PrimaryLast=1).
EXECUTE.

* Count variables and use OMS again to determine max.
COMPUTE VarCount = $CASENUM.
DATASET DECLARE PRECOUNT.
OMS
  /SELECT TABLES
  /IF COMMANDS=['Descriptives'] SUBTYPES=['Descriptive Statistics']
  /DESTINATION FORMAT=SAV NUMBERED=TableNumber_
   OUTFILE='PRECOUNT' VIEWER=YES
  /TAG='Descriptives'.
DESCRIPTIVES VARIABLES=VarCount
  /STATISTICS=MAX.
OMSEND TAG = ['Descriptives'].
DATASET ACTIVATE PRECOUNT.

* Reduce to one line, cleanup and add identifiers.
SELECT IF ~SYSMIS(Maximum).
STRING FileName (A50).
COMPUTE FileName = 'FILENAME.SAV'.
RENAME VARIABLES (N = N_PRE).
ADD FILES FILE *
    /KEEP FileName N_PRE.
EXECUTE.
DATASET CLOSE COUNT.

* Merge data.
GET FILE='DATAFILE_NEW.sav'.
DATASET NAME MergeData WINDOW=FRONT.
DATASET ACTIVATE Data.
ADD FILES /FILE=*
  /FILE='MergeData'.
EXECUTE.
DATASET CLOSE MergeData.

* Do another OMS run to check post_N.
DATASET DECLARE COUNT.
OMS
  /SELECT TABLES
  /IF COMMANDS=['Frequencies'] SUBTYPES=['Frequencies']
  /DESTINATION FORMAT=SAV NUMBERED=TableNumber_
   OUTFILE='COUNT' VIEWER=YES
  /TAG='Frequencies'.
FREQUENCIES ALL.
OMSEND TAG = ['Frequencies'].

* Retain only variable names and remove duplicates.
DATASET ACTIVATE COUNT.
ADD FILES FILE *
    /KEEP Label_,.
EXECUTE.
SORT CASES BY Label_(A).
MATCH FILES
  /FILE=*
  /BY Label_
  /FIRST=PrimaryFirst
  /LAST=PrimaryLast.
DO IF (PrimaryFirst).
COMPUTE  MatchSequence=1-PrimaryLast.
ELSE.
COMPUTE  MatchSequence=MatchSequence+1.
END IF.
LEAVE  MatchSequence.
FORMATS  MatchSequence (f7).
COMPUTE  InDupGrp=MatchSequence>0.
SORT CASES InDupGrp(D).
MATCH FILES
  /FILE=*
  /DROP=PrimaryFirst InDupGrp MatchSequence.
SELECT IF (PrimaryLast=1).
EXECUTE.

* Count variables and use OMS again to determine max.
COMPUTE VarCount = $CASENUM.
DATASET DECLARE POSTCOUNT.
OMS
  /SELECT TABLES
  /IF COMMANDS=['Descriptives'] SUBTYPES=['Descriptive Statistics']
  /DESTINATION FORMAT=SAV NUMBERED=TableNumber_
   OUTFILE='POSTCOUNT' VIEWER=YES
  /TAG='Descriptives'.
DESCRIPTIVES VARIABLES=VarCount
  /STATISTICS=MAX.
OMSEND TAG = ['Descriptives'].
DATASET ACTIVATE POSTCOUNT.

* Reduce to one line, cleanup and add identifiers.
SELECT IF ~SYSMIS(Maximum).
STRING FileName (A50).
COMPUTE FileName = 'FILENAME.SAV'.
RENAME VARIABLES (N = N_POST).
ADD FILES FILE *
    /KEEP FileName N_POST.
EXECUTE.
DATASET CLOSE COUNT.
        
* Merge the post and precount and add to checklist.
DATASET ACTIVATE PRECOUNT.
MATCH FILES /FILE=*
  /TABLE='POSTCOUNT'
  /BY FileName.
EXECUTE.
DATASET ACTIVATE CheckList.
ADD FILES /FILE=*
  /FILE='PRECOUNT'.
EXECUTE.
DATASET CLOSE PRECOUNT.
DATASET CLOSE POSTCOUNT.
```

This does what I want. Get a pre-merge measurement, a post-merge measurement, links them together and adds them to a predifined checklist, which is processed at the end (simple post_n minus pre_n caluclation to show which files are off). But we're talking about 50-100 small datasets to be done this way, which is 150 lines-ish per dataset.

The syntax is generated through matlab with some specific inputs from a variable database, so writing it is not the problem. It's just a convoluted mess. Any ideas to streamline this code?

Regards.

EDIT: Thanks to @eli-k for supplying a much more elegant solution (the whole syntax previously took 4-5 minutes to run, this is much quicker, since it doesn't have to do a FREQUENCIES command on a big dataset every iteration).

I updated the macro a little bit to allow for some extra customization (and to allow a pre and post merge execution).

```
DEFINE !countVars (outputvar = !TOKENS(1) 
/datasetname = !TOKENS(1))

* Figure out number of variables from Dictionary.
DATASET DECLARE  tmp.
OMS /SELECT TABLES /IF COMMANDS=['File Information'] SUBTYPES=['Variable Information'] 
    /DESTINATION FORMAT=SAV OUTFILE='tmp' VIEWER=NO.
DISPLAY DICTIONARY.
OMSEND.
DATASET DECLARE !datasetname.
DATASET ACTIVATE tmp.
OMS
  /SELECT TABLES /IF COMMANDS=['Frequencies'] SUBTYPES=['Frequencies']
  /DESTINATION FORMAT=SAV OUTFILE=!datasetname VIEWER=NO
  /TAG='Frequencies'.
FREQ COMMAND_.
OMSEND TAG = ['Frequencies'].
DATASET ACTIVATE !datasetname.
DATASET CLOSE tmp.
RENAME VARIABLES (Frequency = !outputvar).
ADD FILES FILE * /KEEP !outputvar.
EXECUTE.
!ENDDEFINE.

!countVars outputvar=N_PRE datasetname=PRECOUNT.
STRING FileName (A50).
COMPUTE FileName = 'FILENAME'.
EXECUTE.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way, using both OMS and a macro. The macro will use OMS in order to give you a count of variables in the active dataset.

```
define !countVars ()
dataset name orig.
DATASET DECLARE  tmp.
OMS /SELECT TABLES /IF COMMANDS=['File Information'] SUBTYPES=['Variable Information'] 
    /DESTINATION FORMAT=SAV OUTFILE='tmp' VIEWER=no.
display dictionary.
omsend.
dataset activate tmp.
freq Command_.
dataset activate orig.
dataset close tmp.
!enddefine.
```

Now that the macro is defined you can call it at any point in the syntax like this:

```
!countVars .
```

and see the number of variables in the active dataset under "frequency" in the output table.

Comment: Thanks for this much more elegant solution. I thought the DISPLAY Dictionary function was discontinued. Very good to see it isn't. This I can use for some scripts to check data quality. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness: Getting the variable count using SPSS's builtin python methods is pretty straightforward.

```
begin program.
import spss
print(spss.GetVariableCount())
end program.
```

This snippet simply prints the number of variables in the active dataset to the output window. Assigning the value to a variable periodically throughout your script would make it pretty easy to track the number of variables across multiple merges.